# Calculate reverse running total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get rid of using cursors in my project (SQL Server 2012). And I need to prepare query which calculates reverse (with subtraction) running total.

Let me explain on example.

I have the following data set:

```
Id  AppId   CaseId  Amount  Balance
1   2       123     16.48   43.29
2   2       123     5.01    43.29
3   2       123     2.25    43.29
4   4       123     16.48   43.29
5   4       123     5.01    43.29
6   4       123     2.25    43.29
7   10      789     2       10
8   11      789     4       10
```

I need to get following data set:

```
Id  AppId   CaseId  Amount  Balance Total
1   2       123     16.48   43.29   25.81
2   2       123     5.01    43.29   20.8
3   2       123     2.25    43.29   18.55
4   4       123     16.48   43.29   2.07
5   4       123     5.01    43.29   -2.94
6   4       123     2.25    43.29   -5.19
7   10      789     2       10      8
8   11      789     4       10      4
```

I've tried to use LAG and SUM() OVER() but I can't understand how to use it correctly.

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: what should happen if 2 or more rows with same `caseID` have different `balance`?

Comment: What does "reversive" mean? "reverse" or "recursive"?

Comment: In my case - every single CaseId should have the same Balance. Situation which you've described is impossible.

Comment: "Reversive" - mean opposite, reverse, backward. Sorry for misunderstandings. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `MIN() OVER()` and `SUM() OVER()`:

```
SELECT *, 
       MIN(Balance) OVER(PARTITION BY CaseId) - 
       SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY Id) Total
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY Id;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=63aa1bfd21bc768df1a6adb1699f3c37) of it.

Comment: Many thanks to you! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Nice. I'm not sure whether `MIN(balance)` is the most appropriate. The OP has to clarify: @whitebeast what should happen if 2 or more rows with same `caseID` have different `balance`?

Comment: And if they are all identical, you could use `FIRST_VALUE(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY Id) - ...`. I think that would make it a bit more efficient than MIN (due to the same exact window and that MIN has to check all values in a partition before returning the result). Or just `balance - ...`